# Cron job bash script to restart desktop sharing?

Tags: 12.04, bash, cron, remote-desktop

I'm having trouble with desktop sharing crashing while during remote sessions. Is there a way to set cron to check and restart, if necessary, the desktop sharing application with a bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "`pgrep vino-server`" = "" ]; then
   DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/lib/vino/vino-server --sm-client-disable >/dev/null 2>&1 &
fi
```

Don't forget to give it execute permission: `chmod +x /path/to/script`. Then run `crontab -e` and add this line:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script
```

Comment: Thank You! This really helped. Otherwise, I'd have to ssh in and restart it manually..